# Django: get the id from on model to add it to another

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models

I want to basicaly generate 2 database entries in 2 different models when only one is triggered.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    entrya= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rnum = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    entryb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Child(models.Model):
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    rnum = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amounta= models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now when a form to make the parent is made, i automatically want a blank `Child` entry in the database

**Forms.py**

```
class RNumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ['entrya', 'rnum', 'entryb']
```

So next, here i want to make both database entries:

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def rnum(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            addrnum = RNumForm(request.POST or None)
            if addrnum.is_valid():
                addrnum.instance.user_id = request.user.id
                addrnum.save()

                rnum_new = addrnum.instance.rnum
                rnum_id_query = Parent.objects.filter(user=request.user, rnum = rnum_new).values("id")
                print(rnum_id_query)
                rnum_id = rnum_id_query.id
                print(rnum_id)                  

                Child.objects.create(
                    amounta= "0",
                    rnum = rnum_id,
                    user_id = request.user.id,
                    )
```

in my terminal i always get this printed out as an error

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1}]>
{'id': 1}


Cannot assign "{'id': 1}": "Child.rnum" must be a "Parent" instance.
```

Does anybody have an idea or could anybody help please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look into the concept of "Foreign Keys".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make use of the instance wrapped in the form:

```
addrnum = RNumForm(request.POST or None)
if addrnum.is_valid():
    addrnum.instance.user_id = request.user.id
    parent = addrnum.save()

    Child.objects.create(
        amounta= '0',
        rnum = parent,
        user_id = request.user.id,
    )
```